# Rails 3- Devise - Sign in error after login with facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I setup devise & omniauth to authen,
After login with facebook, i create a user and generate a password for user

```
user = User.new :fullname => auth_hash['extra']['raw_info']['name'], 
:email =>auth_hash['extra']['raw_info']['email'], 
:encrypted_password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
```

But when i try to login with my facebook user (http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in) , i have a error :

```
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash in Devise::SessionsController#create 
invalid hash
```

Request

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"/xA0goLirKlI2YWSLSMQk+3a8xDrVmrhqIjhILh0OME=",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"xxx@gmail.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "remember_me"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Sign in"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Devise by default uses bcrypt's encrypted password algorithm, and so my guess is that it's having problems with you trying to input the encrypted version of the password manually. Have you tried simply setting a :password value as opposed to :encrypted_password? As in:

```
user = User.new :fullname => auth_hash['extra']['raw_info']['name'], 
:email =>auth_hash['extra']['raw_info']['email'], 
:password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
```

Comment: Yes, i have tried.
But rails raise another error :
unknown attribute: password

Comment: Oh, this is my stupid error,
I add : :database_authenticatable to user.rb model and all solved

Comment: Good to know, glad you figured it out.